# Ambiguous function overload in C++

Tags: c++

I am following right now a C++ coursera-course, trying to compile example from here: [Ira Pohl’s C++ by Dissection](https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~pohl/C++BD/05Chap/rational.cpp) with both g++ and intel's c++ compilers.

got some errors with both compilers, like this on every call to greater:

```
rational.cpp(69): error: "greater" is ambiguous
      << greater(i, j);
         ^



/***************************************************************
*  C++ by Dissection    By Ira Pohl           Addison Wesley    
*  Chapter 5    Ctors, Dtors, Conversion, and Operator Overloading
*  Compiled with Borland C++ Builder Version 5.0   Summer 2001  
******************************************************************/

//Overloading functions

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


// Overloading functions

class rational {
public:
   rational(int n = 0) : a(n), q(1) { }
   rational(int i, int j) : a(i), q(j) { }
   rational(double r) : a(static_cast<long>
                         (r * BIG)), q(BIG) { }
   void  print() const { cout << a << " / " << q; }
   operator double() 
              { return static_cast<double>(a) / q; }
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const rational& x);
   friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, rational& x);
   friend bool operator>(rational w, rational z);
private:
   long  a, q;
   enum { BIG = 100 };
};



ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const rational& x)
{
    return (out << x.a << " / " << x.q << '\t');
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, rational& x)
{
   return (in >> x.a >> x.q);
}


bool operator>(rational w, rational z)
{ 
   return (static_cast<double>(w.a) / w.q >            static_cast<double>(z.a) / z.q); 
}


inline int     greater(int i, int j) 
      { return (i > j ? i : j); }

inline double  greater(double x, double y)
      { return (x > y ? x : y); }

inline rational greater(rational w, rational z)
      { return (w > z ? w : z); }

int main()
{
   int     i = 10, j = 5;
   float   x = 7.0;
   double  y = 14.5;
   rational w(10), z(3.5), zmax;

   cout << "\ngreater(" << i << ", " << j << ") = "
        << greater(i, j);
   cout << "\ngreater(" << x << ", " << y << ") = "
        << greater(x, y);
   cout << "\ngreater(" << i << ", ";
   z.print();
   cout << ") = "
        << greater(static_cast<rational>(i), z);
   zmax = greater(w, z);
   cout << "\ngreater("; 
   w.print();
   cout << ", ";
   z.print();
   cout << ") = ";
   zmax.print();
   cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `greater` function is present in the imported [`std` namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) as well as the source file, so the compiler can't decide which one should be used.

Maybe this wasn't the case with Borland C++ 5.0, so the code compiled fine back then. This is a nice example why `using namespace std` is usually a bad idea.

You might try to remove that declaration and manually add an explicit `std::` prefix where needed (the compiler will tell you).

Comment: You mean there is a `std::greater()` function in the `iostream` library? Because I can't find it on the docs.

Comment: `greater` seems to only exist `functional` unless I'm missing something.

Comment: As per the link given - `Defined in header <functional>` - the OP here does not include it.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The `std::greater` function is defined *at least* in the `<functional>` header, but this header might be pulled in by `<iostream>` implicitely.

Comment: @Carcigenicate But there is nothing prohibiting that one header inclues another.

Comment: ...and see G++' output for a proof. One of the canditates is `/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:338:12: note:  template<class _Tp> struct std::greater` here with the tested version.

Comment: @Waldheinz according to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/): `Including this header [[iostream]] may automatically include other headers, such as <ios>, <streambuf>, <istream>, <ostream> and/or <iosfwd>`. Doesn't this mean that no other headers are included?

Comment: @deviantfan Fair enough.

Comment: @Al.G. "such as" means that are examples. And again, look at the full compiler output (of one compiler and stdlib), the relevant part posted above. Chain for me: iostream => ostream => ios => bits/ios_base.h => bits/locale_classes.h => string => bits/stl_function.h